# How to highlight the parent item in active state without the children being affected in wordpress navigation?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've been trying to code a wordpress drop down menu.  Please see here: http://www.hongkong8.info/.

I have almost got it to behave the way I want except one thing.  When I click on the "ABOUT" link, that triggers the active state which is the color #111154. this is correct, however if you roll over the "ABOUT" link again you see that its child pages "ABOUT 1" and "ABOUT 2" are also highlight with the color #111154, this is not what I want.  I just want the parent page to be highlighted in the active state color and not its children pages.  Its children pages should have the color of #01011D.

The menu uses the default wordpress classes .ie register_nav_menus etc. I have tried different css classes but can't pinpoint the right class.  My feeling was that it could be targetted using .current-menu-item, but I don't know how to target the child menu items

Have included the CSS for the nav menu below.  Any insight is much appreciated!

```css
/* Navigation Menus */
.site-nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after {content: ""; display: table;}
.site-nav ul:after {clear:both;}
.site-nav ul {*zoom: 1;}

.site-nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
}

.site-nav ul ul {
 display:none;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background: #01011D;
}

.site-nav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 width:130px;
}

.site-nav ul ul a:hover{
 background-color: #ECECEC;
 display: block;
}

.site-nav ul ul li,
.site-nav ul ul a {
 float: none;
}

/* site header menu*/

div.nav-wrapper{
 width: 960px;
 background: #1c137f; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1c137f 2%, #0b093c 27%, #0b093c 70%, #020014 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%,#1c137f), color-stop(27%,#0b093c), color-stop(70%,#0b093c), color-stop(100%,#020014)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1c137f 2%,#0b093c 27%,#0b093c 70%,#020014 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1c137f 2%,#0b093c 27%,#0b093c 70%,#020014 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1c137f 2%,#0b093c 27%,#0b093c 70%,#020014 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1c137f 2%,#0b093c 27%,#0b093c 70%,#020014 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1c137f', endColorstr='#020014',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
 border-top:solid 1px #fff;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 1px #040315;
 border-bottom:solid 1px #7E0000;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 z-index: 20;
}



.site-header nav ul li a:link,
.site-header nav ul li a:visited{
 display: block;
 padding: 7px 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #ECECEC; /*hover state*/
}

.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited {
 background-color: #111154; /*active state*/
 color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the structure, you could probably use the direct descendant selector to target only the anchor at the first level, like this:

```
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:link,
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:visited {
    background-color: #111154; /*active state*/
    color: #FFF;
}
```

This shouldn't apply the #111154 background color to the anchors in the sub menu.